# Email alerts from VPS to Gmail

Tags: email, vps

I am planning to fire up a VPS running Debian. I want it to send me email alerts.

However, I don't want to bother with a separate local email client on my machine; I use Gmail and that should be sufficient. Moreover, I want the emails to get to me even if the server goes down, so checking a POP3/IMAP mailbox on the server won't work at all. (In fact, I want to put in a watchdog that send an email and then intentionally brings the server down in some cases)

What's the best way to do it, given that I don't want to keep a password for my Gmail on the server?

Comment: Have you looked into [app passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)? Might be a viable alternative to having your Gmail password on the server.

Comment: You can't send emails from the server from your gmail account without signing into gmail and that means supplying a password - most likely an app password, because Google is increasingly finicky. If that's a hard no, then pick a free email account from the several choices (or shell out a few bucks for an email account from your domain provider) and set up nullmailer to send your emails.

Comment: Note that Gmail 's application passwords are meant to solve exactly that issue: you generate a single purpose (in this case: sending emails) single usage (that specific server) password, so that potential abuse is limited to the powers the server had anyways, and do you can store that password on the server. If the server gets compromised, it does no more damage than letting the attacker send emails, until you deactivate that application password.

Comment: Wait, how do I create an application password that allows sending of emails but does not allow reading of emails? I could not find this possibility.